# Delphi - change text color based on current record value

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

using db controls connected to a FireBird database. and I have a simple dblabel I want to change text color based on current value for current record

The user navigate using the dbnavigator and I wrote code in the navigator button click. but there is a problem the code always read the previous record value not the current one so the color is wrong !! for example:

```
procedure <navigator button click>;
begin
  if table1.FieldByName('field1').AsString = 'val1' then
    <dblabel.textcolor> := red
  else
    <dblabel.textcolor> := green; 

end;
```

but as I said the value is one record behind. why is that and what is the best approach to change label text color ?

Thanks

Comment: dblabel? or dbtext? the dbnavigator and dbtext are using the same datasource, right?

Comment: is there a way to choose more than one answer ?

Comment: no, only one answer. You can put comment on another, saying how it solves your problem. Your comment can help others with similar problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a bunch of events!

- TDataSource.OnDataChange
- TJvDataSource.OnDatasetScrolled
- DataSet.AfterScroll plus DataSet.AfterOpen

Demo EXE: http://rghost.ru/40321071 (leftmost button is "download")

DFM:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu, biMinimize]
  BorderStyle = bsSingle
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 301
  ClientWidth = 685
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -13
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnHide = FormHide
  PixelsPerInch = 120
  TextHeight = 16
  object dbgrd1: TDBGrid
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 425
    Height = 277
    DataSource = ds1
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -13
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object edtL_DS_ODC: TLabeledEdit
    Left = 448
    Top = 24
    Width = 200
    Height = 24
    EditLabel.Width = 163
    EditLabel.Height = 16
    EditLabel.Caption = 'TDataSource.OnDataChange'
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 1
  end
  object edtL_JDS_ODS: TLabeledEdit
    Left = 448
    Top = 104
    Width = 200
    Height = 24
    EditLabel.Width = 194
    EditLabel.Height = 16
    EditLabel.Caption = 'TJvDataSource.OnDatasetScrolled'
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object edtL_T_AS: TLabeledEdit
    Left = 448
    Top = 184
    Width = 200
    Height = 24
    EditLabel.Width = 117
    EditLabel.Height = 16
    EditLabel.Caption = 'TDataSet.AfterScroll'
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 3
  end
  object pnl1: TPanel
    Left = 480
    Top = 48
    Width = 105
    Height = 25
    BevelOuter = bvLowered
    Caption = 'pnl1'
    Color = clBlack
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 4
    object dbtxt1: TDBText
      Left = 24
      Top = 6
      Width = 65
      Height = 17
      DataField = 'Dummy'
      DataSource = ds1
    end
  end
  object pnl2: TPanel
    Left = 480
    Top = 128
    Width = 105
    Height = 25
    BevelOuter = bvLowered
    Caption = 'pnl1'
    Color = clBlack
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 5
    object dbtxt2: TDBText
      Left = 24
      Top = 6
      Width = 65
      Height = 17
      DataField = 'Dummy'
      DataSource = ds1
    end
  end
  object pnl3: TPanel
    Left = 480
    Top = 208
    Width = 105
    Height = 25
    BevelOuter = bvLowered
    Caption = 'pnl1'
    Color = clBlack
    ParentBackground = False
    TabOrder = 6
    object dbtxt3: TDBText
      Left = 24
      Top = 6
      Width = 65
      Height = 17
      DataField = 'Dummy'
      DataSource = ds1
    end
  end
  object dbnvgr1: TDBNavigator
    Left = 439
    Top = 260
    Width = 240
    Height = 25
    DataSource = ds1
    Kind = dbnHorizontal
    TabOrder = 7
  end
  object ds1: TDataSource
    DataSet = data
    OnDataChange = ds1DataChange
    Left = 24
    Top = 80
  end
  object ds2: TJvDataSource
    DataSet = data
    OnDataSetScrolled = ds2DataSetScrolled
    Left = 64
    Top = 80
  end
  object data: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    AfterScroll = dataAfterScroll
    Left = 24
    Top = 24
    object fldValue: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Value'
    end
    object fldDummy: TIntegerField
      FieldName = 'Dummy'
    end
  end
end
```

PAS:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ds1: TDataSource;
    ds2: TJvDataSource;
    data: TClientDataSet;
    fldValue: TIntegerField;
    fldDummy: TIntegerField;
    dbgrd1: TDBGrid;
    edtL_DS_ODC: TLabeledEdit;
    edtL_JDS_ODS: TLabeledEdit;
    edtL_T_AS: TLabeledEdit;
    dbtxt1: TDBText;
    pnl1: TPanel;
    pnl2: TPanel;
    dbtxt2: TDBText;
    pnl3: TPanel;
    dbtxt3: TDBText;
    dbnvgr1: TDBNavigator;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure dataAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
    procedure ds1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
    procedure ds2DataSetScrolled(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormHide(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure ShowIt(const el: TLabeledEdit; Const color, value: integer); overload;
    procedure ShowIt(const el: TLabeledEdit); overload;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i,j,k: integer;
begin
   data.CreateDataSet;

   for i := 1 to 20 do begin
       j := Random(100) - 50;
       k := Random(20);
       data.AppendRecord([j,k]);
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormHide(Sender: TObject);
begin
  data.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowIt(const el: TLabeledEdit);
begin
  ShowIt(el, fldValue.AsInteger, fldDummy.AsInteger);
end;

procedure TForm1.ShowIt(const el: TLabeledEdit; const color, value: integer);
begin
  if el = nil then exit;

  if color < 0 then el.Color := clYellow
               else el.Color := clWhite;

  el.Text := IntToStr(color) + ' ==> ' + IntToStr(value);

  dbtxt1.Font.Color := edtL_DS_ODC.color;
  dbtxt2.Font.Color := edtL_JDS_ODS.color;
  dbtxt3.Font.Color := edtL_T_AS.color;
end;

procedure TForm1.dataAfterScroll(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
 ShowIt(edtL_T_AS);
end;

procedure TForm1.ds1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin
 ShowIt(edtL_DS_ODC);
end;

procedure TForm1.ds2DataSetScrolled(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowIt(edtL_JDS_ODS);
end;
```

Comment: thanks but how I can access the form controls from a datamodule to use the afterscroll event without doing a circular reference ?

Comment: to avoid circular reference, put one uses declaration under interface and the other uses declaration under implementation sections.

Comment: If your table always uses that form - then why use DataModule ? Put tables on form and use locally.  /// If those tables are used by different forms, then don't set events in DesignTime. Let you form have the procedure readymade, then you form would use its OnShow and OnHide event to assign those dataset events to form's method.
///
As a hybrid approach, you may put DataSource onto form and do those local procedures locally. All you would have to do it bind form's DataSource to DataModule's DataSet

Comment: Thanks alot for all your efforts and time guys I appreciate that...I just discovered a very odd problem. after debugging and step through code the afterscroll event work but the dbtext does not get painted with the correct color although the code line execute normally !!! this is very strange....any ideas ?

Comment: it should not re-paint while tracing OnAfterScroll in debugger btw, only after you let the program run. Hopefully, you did give it a chance ?

Comment: most probably use some other dbtext. or maybe VCL styles are used or whatever.
i still think you'd better put one more DataSource onto the form itself and use its event locally without crossing units boundary.

Comment: I can not write actual code (NDA). but I am going crazy here after I made a new test form it now work. in the new form and the original one too !!!

Comment: if the form or its parent got disabled, then WM_PAINT message could be lost in a way. Or whatever. I feel your pain but under NDA your are the only person capable to refine, minimize and debug. Good luck.

Comment: You can try PostMessage to the From1.Handle with WM_USER or such.
Then have a handler in TForm1 for it updating the component. And look if that handler be called.

Another trick i saw was using TForm.Action to assign it OnIdle handler, so it would poll the dataset column value and update the colour asynchronously. Maybe async polling would produce better results.

Comment: @Arioch'The Thanks for all the advices. I got the updated code from another developer PC with broken reference error for the main form. the error was saying unrecognized reference to the mainform events !! maybe something wrong was done cause that and the color paint problem.

Comment: maybe there was .BeginUpdate of a kind...

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/02/22/1742084.aspx

Comment: the only thing I use BeginUpdate is with devexpress grid to make a filter at run time.

Comment: i told "of a kind" - in the link above there shown API that any Windows can make any other non-updateable without VCL.
Just a blind guess though

Answer (score 3):

`OnButtonClick` event of the navigator fires before the active record in dataset will be changed. One of the possible solutions will be to hook your code to the `OnAfterScroll` event of the DataSet.

Comment: Then name the components and show you exact code including properties of those components. i uploaded the example below. Expect for initial AfterOpen timeframe - it "just works"

Answer (score 1):

use DataSource.OnDataChange event handler

Comment: Unfortunately it's not navigation event. OnDataChange will be fired when the field's data will be changed.

Comment: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/DB_TDataSource_OnDataChange.html

It claims that scrolling would call it too!